# DPpackage installation

Tags: r

I have used the chunk of code

```
packageurl <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DPpackage/DPpackage_1.1-7.tar.gz"
install.packages(packageurl, repos=NULL, type="source")
```

And also istalled rtools40.
But still receiving error message downloading the package--

- > installing *source* package 'DPpackage' ...
  > ** package 'DPpackage' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  > ** using staged installation
  > ** libs
  > Warning in system(cmd) : 'make' not found
  > ERROR: compilation failed for package 'DPpackage'
- > removing 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/DPpackage'
  > Warning in install.packages :
  > installation of package ‘C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp0CbVQF/downloaded_packages/DPpackage_1.1-7.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: Looks like you are trying to compile a package from source on windows. Have you downloaded and installed [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html)? You will need that in order to compile new packages. You'll need to restart R after installing. What do you get when you run `Sys.which("make")` in your R console?

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But now new problem arises. I am trying to load any package but its saying library load failure. Specified module could not be found. Stats.dll like something. And i cannont use any package in R like ggplot2 etc.